# Can the 'T' part in a generic List(Of T) somehow be a variable?

Tags: vb.net, list, generics

I have a function with no specified return type that returns a generic List(Of T) depending on the enum `type` input argument, thus:

```
Public Function GetTypeList(type as TypeListEnum)
    Select Case type
        Case TypeListEnum.A
            'create result As List(Of A)
            Return result
        Case TypeListEnum.B
            'create result As List(Of B)
            Return result
        ...etc.
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

The lines of code to create the result are identical in each block – except for the part defining which list type to return – so I was thinking it would be good if I could somehow specify what the T will be with a variable, instead of having those *almost* identical blocks of code in multiple case blocks.

Is there any way to do this?

And if not is there another (maybe *better*) way to return different generic lists depending on an input argument?

Comment: High odds that this function should itself be generic.  But it [is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: This can be done using generics.

Comment: Where EXACTLY does the value for the `type` parameter come from, i.e. how EXACTLY are you calling this method?  I would agree with @HansPassant that the most likely solution is to reimplement the method you have as generic.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, what do you mean, *"where does `type` come from?"* It's a basic public enum, so the function is called with e.g. `Dim myList as List(Of Booking) = GetTypeList(TypeListEnum.Booking)`.

Comment: So you mean that you're just hard-coding it then?  If so then you absolutely should be using a generic method and using `Dim myList = GetTypeList(Of Booking)()` instead.  By the way, you obviously have `Option Strict Off` and that's bad.  That's the only way the code you currently have could compile so it's obviously bad code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: No, the only place I have `Option Strict Off` is in the specific class with *this* function, which is necessary to have its return type unspecified. I'm pretty sure public enums are unaffected by Option Strict, so I don't know what you're beef is with it. In my usage here it's basically just a way of explicitly telling the function what type of list I want returned, but using an enum gives me a group of logically named options and their underlying integer values are unimportant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a type you expect as a generic constraint for the function

```
Public Function GetList(Of T)() AS List(Of T)
    Select GetType(T) 
        Case GetType(First)
            Return New List(Of First) From { New First() }.Cast(Of T)()
        Case GetType(Second)
            Return New List(Of Second) From { New Second() }.Cast(Of T)()
        Case Else
            Return New List(Of T)()
    End Select
End Function
```

Consumption of the method would be slightly more readable than using dedicated enum.

```
Dim myList As List(Of First) = GetList(Of First)()
Dim myList As List(Of Second) = GetList(Of Second)()
```

Notice that you need explicitly cast list of results into generic list `List(Of T)`.
In your particular case you probably will have some common constraint which you can use for generic types.

Also, unless you want to throw an exception for not configured type, I would suggest to be kind to consumers of your method and return an empty list instead of `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I've just tried this out and although it *does* work, benchmarking shows it is considerably slower over many iterations than my existing enum evaluation method. Performance is a crucial factor for this function, so I can't use it, unfortunately. But it's still a good answer to my question (which didn't mention performance) and will hopefully show others how to do this if performance isn't an issue for them.

Comment: It depends on how you are creating a list. You can cast all object in one iteration and then turn it into a List

Comment: I can't see why using a generic method would affect performance significantly.  I'd guess that you're doing something else wrong, but we can't know whether you are or what it might be without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: The whole `Switch` and `GetType()` here is unnecessary. Also, why do you populate the list with one item? That wasn't in the original code.

Comment: @Vilx-, switch is based on OP's example, where, as I understand, different type has different logic to create a list.

Comment: @Vilx-, OP's example has no code for creating a list at all. I would can to copy it from there, but wanted to warn of possible casting issues when method signature returns generic `List(Of T)` and code returns `List(Of SomethingSpecific)`.

Comment: @Antagony, _Performance is a crucial factor for this function_ - I would make a guess that performance bottle neck is a logic which creates a lists, which you successfully hiding. Are actually going to call method which creates collection of something in a long loop?

Comment: @Fabio: You're right! I started over from scratch and found no discernible overhead in a thousand iterations, so I must have got something wrong first time around. Sorry about that. Anyway, I've decided I'm going to split it out into separate functions as Vilx- suggested elsewhere, but I've saved your snippet as a useful way to return an unknown list type from a generalized function, in case I need something similar in future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an **enum value** and a **data type** don't really have anything in common. There's no "built in" way to go from one to the other. So you'll need a **mapping** of some sorts anyway, something thay says "for this enum value, take this type".

One way to do it is your switch statement. I actually like it and I think that it will also have a good performance. Readibility is pretty good too - you can instantly see which enum value maps to which type.

Alternatively you could make some sort of `Dictionary` that maps enum values to `Type`s. You won't have a switch, but you'll need to use Reflection to create an instance. That will be slower.

**Added:**

If you're OK with changing the function signature as per [Fabio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812805/41360), you can really improve things:

```
Public Function GetList(Of T)() AS List(Of T)
    Return New List(Of T)()
End Function
```

This will be both faster and easier to read. But at this point you have to ask - what's the point in putting this in a separate function at all? Why not just call `New List(Of T)()` instead where you need it?

Comment: Thanks Vilx-. After trying out Fabio's suggestion and finding it affected performance without making any difference to readability (IMO), I'm inclined to agree that what I already have performs better than any use of Reflection, so I guess I'll stick with it.

Comment: @Antagony - Fabio uses needless reflection. His solution could be made much prettier without it. I didn't question the use of the enum, but if it's OK for you to change your method signature from `Public Function GetTypeList(type as TypeListEnum)` to `Public Function GetList(Of T)() AS List(Of T)` then the whole thing can be made MUCH nicer indeed!

Comment: @Antagony, `GetType` is not using Reflection, `GetType` will get type during compile type, so it would be impossible to produce some performance issues during runtime because of `GetType` usage.

Comment: @Fabio - `GetType(T)` is runtime... and the others also emit a few instructions that get the Type... but OK, I agree, it's unlikely to be an issue. I'm starting to wonder how Antagony did his comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Vlix-, I'm busy on another job at the moment, but I will try it out when I get time later. As for calling the lists directly: I wanted to keep the question simple so I didn't mention that this function is actually in a data layer and pulls data using `Dapper.Query` to populate lists of the types specified, for use in the UI.

Comment: @Fabio: Perhaps I got something wrong when trying out your suggestion, but I used a stopwatch to measure execution time in the calling sub – which goes on to draw some graphics in the UI, based on the fetched data – and averaged it out scrolling through hundreds pages of data. With my enum method it was averaging at around 14ms, whereas with your GetType method it was averaging at around 22ms and the scrolling was noticeably slower. Anyway, I'll take another look at it later and try it with Vlax-'s amendment.

Comment: @Antagony - Ahh, that changes things then. In that case you'll need a switch anyway because you can't abstract the list population. Or... You could make a separate method for each type. That's even clearer and no switching.

Comment: @Vilx- `GetType` is an operator and  executed in compile time ;)

Comment: @Vilx-, Yeah I was thinking of doing separate methods anyway, but I'm a bugger for trying make code as concise as possible – hence this question :) – but maybe sometimes it's to the detriment of readability.

Comment: @Antagony, database query is a performance bottleneck. You shouldn't see big performance differences when you try to execute same method but without database queries.

Comment: +1 to Fabio. The method itself pales in comparison to what your DB call is going to take. Don't seek optimizations here. As for multiple methods - there's always tradeoffs. But in this case, consider - would splitting it into multiple methods add a lot of lines of code? I think not. The "switch" there contains about as much overhead as the explicit functions. Would it be clearer to read? I think so.

Comment: "Squeezing too many things together" can become an antipattern. But then, so can "splitting everything apart". There's a delicate balance of how tight/dispersed to make your code. Sometimes even the best experts can't agree. My own "rule of thumb"/intuition is "how easy will it be for someone to trace the path of execution with their finger"? Because when someone else needs to tweak that code (or you yourself need to do it 3 years later), that's what you'll be doing anyway. Try to make it easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have an instance of [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) to be able to tell the type of the generic
2. You can [GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) by name, calling `GetType` and passing the name of the type
3. You can convert an enum to `String` by calling `.ToString()`
4. You have an enum value as input

To sum it up: you need to convert your enum input to `String` by calling `.ToString()` and use it as parameter to `GetType` and use the `Type` returned by `GetType` to instantiate your collection.